# Is the "TypedUseSelectorHook" necessary?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, counter

I am relatively new to React with Typescript so I was following the video which was made by Mark Erikson and Jason Lengstorf on the Redux Toolkit website. Here is the [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9zySeP5vH9c) incase you want to see it.

At approximately 45 minutes in, Mark mentions two constructs which can be seen in the image below. (lines 4 and 5).
[See picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgjoj.png)

I had some trouble understanding these constructs so I made my own counter example using redux toolkit. I did not have to use the typecasts as Mark did. I just want someone to confirm that what I did is also OK and perhaps explain the differences. My code can be found in this Code Sandbox [Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/slices-coquw4?file=/src/Redux/store.ts).

Basically the exports in the store look like this :

```
// Export for provider in App.tsx
export const appStore = configureStore({ reducer: { counterReducer } });

// Export dispatch
export const appDispatch = appStore.dispatch;
export const appState = appStore.getState();
```

Here is how the state is consumed :

```
  let counterValue = useSelector(
    (state) => appStore.getState().counterReducer.value
  );
```

And finally I use this code to dispatch the action:

```
appDispatch(add(1));
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Typesafety is the answer. Now, everything you export has implicit type of 'any' which is not as good as a version with a type.